# Compare Array of objects in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, array, js

I have my old results in result1 and updated values in result2 . If both ids from the 2 arrays are same then i want to change the new value from result2 in result1

```
var result1 = [
    {id:1, name:'Sandra',  email:'Sandra@example.com'},
    {id:2, name:'John',  email:'johnny@example.com'},
    {id:3, name:'Peter',  email:'Peter@example.com'},
    {id:4, name:'Bobby',  email:'Bobby@example.com'}
];

var result2 = [
    {id:2, name:'Andreas', email:'johnny@example.com'},
    {id:4, name:'Season', email:'season@example.com'}
];
```

I want to update the result1 with result2 values like below if Ids are same

```
var result1 = [
    {id:1, name:'Sandra',  email:'Sandra@example.com'},
    {id:2, name:'Andreas',  email:'johnny@example.com'},
    {id:3, name:'Peter',  email:'Peter@example.com'},
    {id:4, name:'Season', email:'season@example.com'}
];
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put `result1` elements in [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) using the `id` as key and the records as value.
Then if you need to update only the existing records, without adding the new values to the map, you can loop over `result2` and add its records to the map only if their `id` is already in the map.

```js
const resultMap = new Map();
// Fill the map with result1 elements
result1.forEach((elem) => {
    resultMap.set(elem.id, elem);
});

// Update the map values
result2.forEach((elem) => {
    if (resultMap.has(elem.id)) {
        resultMap.set(elem.id, elem);
    }
});

result1 = Array.from(resultMap.values());
```

If `result2` can hold only records whose id is in `result1` or if  `result2` may have more records that `result1` and you want to keep the new ones too, you can remove the `if` in `result2` loop.

```js
result2.forEach((elem) => {
    resultMap.set(elem.id, elem);
});
```